# Как сделать кнопку на форме не активной после нажатия?

Tags: javascript, java-ee, jsp

Добрый день!

Возникла проблема с тем, чтобы после нажатия кнопки, форма отправлялась на сервер, кнопка становилась неактивной.

**Сам я делал вот так:**

```
<form action="controller" method="POST" onSubmit="this.send.disabled=true;">
    <input type="hidden" name="command" value="recommendDischarged"/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link">
        <fmt:message key="recommend_discharged" />
    /button>
</form>
```

Но делает только неактивной на время обработки формы.

**Дальше пробовал делать так:**

```
<form action="controller" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="command" value="recommendDischarged"/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link" onClick="this.disabled=true;>
        <fmt:message key="recommend_discharged" />
    /button>
</form>
```

Но тут получается кнопка становится неактивной, но форма на сервлет на отправляется

Вообщем, я думаю, проблема в том, что после нажатия кнопки она становиться не активной, потом идет обработка формы на сервлете, а потом возвращается обратно на ту же страницу, где кнопка опять активна, что логично. Вот как сделать так, чтобы она продолжала быть неактивной?

Буду рад любому совету!

Comment: Можно во внутренней логике написать какую то переменную которая будет определять состояние кнопки при загрузке, либо get запросом оформить

Comment: get запросом нельзя, потому что данный сервлет предполагает вставку значения в бд, а вот насчет переменной я уже думал, но не знаю, насколько так правильно делать. Вот поэтому решил искать решение в js, так сказать, зачем писать велосипед

Comment: А до каких пор кнопка должна быть неактивной?

Comment: после нажатия на кнопку, она должна быть неактивной до перехода на другую страницу,отличной от той, на которой находится кнопка

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17106916/2929220 посмотрите тут